# How to reflect updated cell values during a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make my sheet updates visible once they are done.

I wrote this code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do

```
function sheetResponsivenessTest(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet8');
  if(sheet == undefined){
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet('Sheet8');
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  for(var r = 1 ; r < 3 ; r++){
    for(var c = 1 ; c < 3 ; c++){
      sheet.getRange(r, c, 1, 1).setValue(r + '_' + c);
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

What happens when I run this method is that after a while, I see all values appearing in one shot. While I need to see the cells **being filled** one by one. Increasing the sleep duration didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call spreadsheetApp.flush().
It will cause it to run much slower.

Comment: I have another sheet that updates it's cells once they are updated but I don't `flush` the `SpreadsheetApp` as you directed here. Why would a sheet update it's cells without me having to `flush` the updates ?

Comment: depends on how much data you write to the spreadsheet. flush is not necesary, just makes the update happen right away